Flexbox Equal Height Cards Wrapping Issue
I am trying to create a section that have 3 equal columns/cards. I run into a trouble when I tries to make it works on smaller screen sizes. Each card should wrap on to a new line when the screen size gets smaller than 250px.
The problem could be seen in picture 1:

I set flex-wrap: wrap; for the flex container and flex: 1 250px; for the flex children but they do not seem to work, so I am confused what I have done wrong.
I also want the distance of my paragraph and the titles in the cards to be equal. I have .project with display: flex and have .project p {margin-top: auto} following a guide on creating equal height cards, but it also does not seem to work.



/*PROJECTS*/

.projects {
  margin: 0 12rem;
}


/*CONTAINERS FOR IMAGES*/

.project-image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}


/*CONTAINER */

.projects-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/*ITEMS IN THE CONTAINER*/

.project {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 250px;
}

.project p {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.project img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="projects">
  <h2>Projects</h2>

  <div class="projects-list">
    <div class="project">
      <div class="project-image">
        <img class="library-chatsphere" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="the poster of the NCHU library chatsphere 2024">
      </div>
      <h3 class="projects-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam omnis quibusdam animi. Voluptatibus nobis quo reprehenderit ipsam id quaerat pariatur.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="project">
      <div class="project-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="a background of green leaves">
      </div>
      <h3 class="projects-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit vitae illum quod quisquam provident odit praesentium assumenda quae ipsum sed.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="project">
      <div class="project-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="a background of green leaves">
      </div>
      <h3 class="projects-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit vitae illum quod quisquam provident odit praesentium assumenda quae ipsum sed.</p>
    </div>

  </div>




@easleyfixed, those are Bootstrap classes. How does that help here?

Good point, they NEED Bootstrap to get this done automatically, unless they want to do the math for each screen size by hand.

Hi, hmm... I still don't quite understand what you two are talking about. Is there any way that you suggest would fix the issue? Thanks~
